# typo3 site crawler not indexing

Tags: php, indexing, web-crawler, typo3, typo3-4.5

I am trying to get a page indexed with indexed search and sitecrawler on a old TYPO3 4.5 website - but I have tried almost anything to no avail.

I am running the site crawler and it will get a full list of URLs that can be crawled and I am running throught the entire queue

[image]

I have setup a "Index Configuration"

[image]

and a site crawler

[image]

But it will not index

[image]

the "cache_pages" table also seems to be empty - but caching is enable for all pages.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Did you add and run a scheduler task for crawling through collected URL's?  There should be some status on the queue view - OK, or some error. but there's nothing

Comment: It says OK to all the pages! But nothing gets indexed! But I do have a page at the root that have its own TypoScript template! That page do get indexed but not the pages under!

Comment: Hard to guess, if your pages on lower level contains for an example some COA_INT or USER_INT (non-cached) element(s) the page won't be indexed.

Comment: have you set ` page.config.index_enable = 1` in your typoscript setup?

Comment: I have set index_enable = 1. I somehow suspect the rootpage to course problems. That is indexed but not the children.

Comment: This could very well be a caching issue, then. Check out: http://xavier.perseguers.ch/tutoriels/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html and maybe this might help, too: http://labor.99grad.de/2012/02/08/wenn-indexed_search-nicht-indiziert/

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot showing crawler queue looks good. It seems the crawler is configured correctly, but indexed search is not indexing the pages.
Empty page cache suggests you have cache disabled shomehow.

Indexed search is indexing pages when few conditions are met:

1. page is cacheable (no `page.config.no_cache = 1` in TypoScript, cache is not disabled in page properties, and cache is not disabled from PHP code)
2. there are special markers in the source code  `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->` and `<!-- TYPO3SEARCH_end-->`
3. TypoScript `page.config.index_enable = 1` is set
4. The page is accessed user not logged to Backend or by Crawler

### What you can check is:

- Please verify in TypoScript Object Browser, whether the index_enable and no_cache values have correct values for not indexed pages.
- Enable debug mode in Extension Manager for Crawler and Indexed search
- Click on the number in the "queue id" column for some not indexed page and check the data shown there.
- Double check if "session id" field is empty in indexed search configuration record before you start indexing
- Remove date from "Next indexing date" field from indexed search configuration record

### Few useful links:

- [You can find indexed_search documentation here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/indexed_search/latest/IndexingConfigurations/Configurations/Index.html)
- [Crawler documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/crawler/ExtCrawler/Index.html)
- [Useful tutorial on setting indexed search with crawler](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html)

Comment: Make sure to define "page.config.index_enable = 1" and not simple "config.index_enable = 1". This is what worked for me

Comment: Ok, documentation is good but, after queed all crawled URL's ther a way to catch them all and indexing at one time without clicking in every button "read url" in every URL's line. In my site i have to  index about 3000pages and it is non possible there's no automated way to do this

Answer (score 0):

If none of Tymoteusz suggestions work, check if you are running your website in https mode, with a selfsigned certificate (for ex if you are developing on your local machine). If it is the case, just run your website without https and retest the crawler. I recently tested a TYPO3 6.2 website with crawler and indexed_search properly configured and the pages were never indexed. The error I received in the crawlerlog was an empty Error message and in the database the tx_crawler_queue table showed the value b:0; in the column "result_data". 
Once I passed to http everything worked just fine.

In production it should work just fine using https as long as you're using a valid certificate.